# Write clickable xpath for entire text in different "span" tags but under one "p" tag

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, watir, watir-webdriver

Here's `xpath` that I wrote but it is of not optimum `xpath expression`, I think.

`//div[contains(@class,'config')]/a[contains(.,'student')]/../p[contains(.,'Never logged as ') and contains(.,'admin')]`

HTML is this:

```
<div class="config">
  <a class="something student something " href="something" htmlelement = "something">
     <div class="bla bla"/>
     <div class="bla bls> xyz </div>
     <div class="bla blab">abc</div>
     <span>Allow it</span>
  </a>
  <p>
     <span>Never logged as</span>
     <span class="b">admin.</span>
     <img src="/images/info.png"/>
  </p>
  <div class="bla bla">qwerty</div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is to write a generic `xpath` like this:
`//div[contains(@class,'config')]/a[not(contains(.,'#{$role_type}'))]/../p[contains(.,'#{$condition}')]`

and click on this:
`@browser.link(:xpath => my_xpath).when_present.click`

I am passing only two parameters in above `xpath` "role_type" and "condition", but when I do that it fails to identify it, because text "admin" is in another span.

So how to collect entire span text? I tried this [XPath expression for selecting all text in a given node, and the text of its chldren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424117/xpath-expression-for-selecting-all-text-in-a-given-node-and-the-text-of-its-chl) post too, but here it is giving string as output but I want clickable element not string.

I am using WATIR (Ruby+Cucumber)

Comment: You need to give more context. What library/ programming language are you working with? Post that code. Specifically: What is inside `$condition` and `$role_type`? What do you mean by "clickable XPath"?

Comment: @Mathia Muller Done. `$role_type` and `$condition` are strings. Clickable means , clicking the a tag there.

Comment: Post _all_ of that code, or at least a [minimal, complete and verifiable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And tag the question with the languages you use.

Comment: I think you might be out of luck for using XPath as I do not believe there is a string concatenation feature. Does it really have to be a single XPath - ie are you allowed to make use of additional Watir and Ruby functionality?

Comment: @JustinKo 1. I dunno using `xpath` as identified is good idea or not (I am new to `WATIR+Cucumber`). 2. Yes sure I can use any identifier but I am comfortable with `xpath` so I have been using it. which identifier would you personally suggest for `WATIR+Cucumber` 3. Yes I am allowed to do what you are ideating here, I never thought of that. What I wanted was, I wanted to pass two parameter in this method one is "role_type" another is "condition" which would generate xpath for me at run time, as xpath remains same its just these two parameters changes.

Comment: Are you trying to click the link (as suggested by `browser.link.click`) or the paragraph tag (as that is what xpath examples are returning)?

Comment: I think you need to be more clear as to what you want to accomplish.  Is there more than one div with "configure" for the class?  Is there more than one link with "student" as part of its class?  Is the text in the spans of the paragraph sibling of the link important or part of the criteria for finding the right link to click?  Does that text appear next to other links that do not have class student?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be out of luck for using XPath as I do not believe there is a string concatenation feature (at least in XPath 1.0).

Instead, I would use other Watir and Ruby methods. For example, the following will go through the config div elements and find the one that contains the role link and condition text. From the found element, you can then click its link.

```
$role_type = 'student'
$condition = 'Never logged as admin.'

config = browser.divs(class: 'config').find do |div|
    div.link(class: $role_type).exists? && div.p(text: $condition).exists?
end
config.link.click
```

Comment: while you were away, I was also discussing with one of friend and he sent this to me, but I didnt gets whats going on here.`link_class = span_element(:text => $condition).parent.attribute("class")
    config_state = link_class[/student/]` and then `@browser.span(:text => $condition).parent.click` Would you please care to compare both his and your solution in your answer, which is best practice, and how it is written. I really appreciate that.

Comment: I can see what your friend is doing, though I think there is some missing code - eg `config_state` is not actually used. I do not think that either approach is a better practice. However, I would argue `link_class[/student/]` is not ideal since it will match classes that include "student" not just those with the class "student".

Comment: Actually, I do not think your colleague's `@browser.span(:text => $condition).parent.click` will work. It assumes that the "Never logged as admin." text is in a single span rather than multiples. Maybe they meant to check the paragraph tag - `@browser.p(:text => $condition).parent.click`?

Comment: Thanks @JustinKo and Chuck . I appreciate you give valuable advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to locate the first link that is next to "Never logged on as admin", then

@browser.p(:text => "Never logged as admin").parent.link.click

Otherwise, an approach such as Justin's answer might be needed.